# Slim Route Group not passing url variable to the callback

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to use slim's route groups, but I am having trouble getting the url parameters to pass anything in.

```
$app->group('/contest/:id', function($id) use ($API){
    error_log('THIS IS THE CONTEST ID: '.$id); // id is blank... why?
    $API->authorize('contest', $id);
    $contest = new Contest($id);

    $app->get('', function() use ($contest, $API){
        $data = $contest->getSettings();
        $API->output($data);
    });

    $app->get('/settings', function() use ($contest, $API){
        $data = $contest->getSettings();
        $API->output($data);
    });

    $app->get('/stats', function() use ($contest, $API){
        $data = $contest->getStats();
        $API->output($data);
    });

    $app->get('/fields', function() use ($contest, $API){
        $data = $contest->getFields();
        $API->output($data);
    });
});
```

Why can't I access $id in the callback function? Isn't this the point of route groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce this - with last stable release 2.6.2 - and got (probably) same problem like you.

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for {closure}()

Route params in group could be placed in the callback from their childs:

```php
$app->group('/contest/:id', function() use ($API){

    $app->get('', function($id) use ($contest, $API){
        $API->authorize('contest', $id);
        $contest = new Contest($id);
        $data = $contest->getSettings();
        $API->output($data);
    });
});
```

But yeah it's ugly to authorize in every single route, maybe you could do this in some kind of [middleware](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/middleware/)? I think the last one on the docs page looks good to your needs.

**Edit**

Oh I recently found [this issue](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/926), where @Gisheri already got an answer of a Slim maintainer.

Comment: yah thanks, that is what I ended up doing.. perhaps it will be a feature someday.

Comment: Mh I don't know the implementation in the upcoming Slim3.